# How to get the showing size of current image or image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, size

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="imagescrollviewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <!--<Viewbox>-->
        <Image x:Name="im" Source="{Binding JpgImageSource}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="{Binding stretchstate}" >
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}" ScaleY="{Binding Value,ElementName=scaleslider}" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
        </Image>
        <!--</Viewbox>-->
    </ScrollViewer>
<ToggleButton  Width="80" Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding checkstate}" Content="{Binding checkstate}">
<Slider x:Name="scaleslider" Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Maximum="4" Minimum="0.2" Value="1"/>
```

i use the slider to change the size showing , the togglebutton used to change size showing to adapt current window , but there is a problem , when the size larger than size  when it adapts the window, i cannot make it apadt the window , while it is smaller ,it works.
Or is there any ways to get the size of current image control ,while resizing the window?

Comment: what is your question? Get the image size or adapt the window?

Comment: Your code will works only when the Stretch is set to None.

Comment: @Sankaranni knew it , but when i set the slider's value =2 ,i mean if the size is larger than the window , it did not work

Comment: @lincoln adapt the window